# Designing classes in code first Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, data-annotations, code-first

I am building a online shopping web application. 
I have  four entities :

1. Customers

   - CusomerId
   - Name
   - Address
   - Phone
2. Category

   - CategoryId
   - Category
3. Product

   - ProductId
   - Name
   - Price
   - Category
4. Order

   - OrderId
   - CustomerId
   - ProductId
   - Quantity
   - Amount

Please help me designing the classes so that proper relation(Primary key and foreign key) is maintained.
I tried doing it but database itself was creating foreign key which lead inconsistency.

My Classes:

```
public class Category    
{    
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }    
}

public class Customer    
{    
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string  Email { get; set; }
    public string  Password { get; set; }    
}

public class Order    
{    
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }    
}

public class Product    
{    
    public int ProductId{ get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }    
}
```

The problem is in deciding what should be made primary key and foreign key and how?
Currently database is adding `order_orderid` field in `Product` table as foreign key, itself.

Comment: You should show your image database which has been generated from EF. It would be help for you get correct answer.

Comment: @ToanVo: I have updated my question with some code, please look if you could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `List<Product> Products` in side the `Order`. My my understand this property should not be here. You should create another table are `OrderItem` which will contains `List<Product> Product`. You can download [**NorthWind**](http://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/71634) database to get more understand.

Comeback your problem. You should remove the `List<Product> Products` property out of class `Order` and regenerate database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues:

- Virtual missing on Navigation properties
- consider introducing an OrderItem table or you will need a surrogate key per Item in Order table
- If you want to create the ForeignKey ID field yourself, Annotation or Fluent API is required to tell EF about the that.

It is explained well here
[Entity Framework Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it myself and it works fine now.  Here are the classes:

```
public class Category   
{   
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }  
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }   
}


public class Customer   
{       
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }   
    public string Address { get; set; }  
    public string  Email { get; set; }  
    public string  Password { get; set; }  
}

public class Product   
{  
    public int ProductId{ get; set; }  
    public string ProductName { get; set; }  
    public int Price { get; set; }  
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }  
    public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }  
}   

public class Order   
{  
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }   
    public int OrderID { get; set; }  
    public int ProductId { get; set; }  
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }  
    public string ProductName { get; set; }  
    public int Price { get; set; }  
    public string DeliveryStatus { get;  set; }  
    public virtual Product Products { get; set; }  
    public virtual Customer Customers { get; set; }  
}
```

This gives me perfect database design as i wanted.